# Laravel 5 Models Folder

Tags: php, laravel, model, laravel-artisan

I have a directory called `models` inside `app/` where I place all my model classes. Now I want to change the directory where the following command outputs the generated classes

```
php artisan make:model SomeModel
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can't and, if you're hewing to Laravel's version of the universe, you shouldn't. Laravel 5 provides, and assumes, a PSR-4 naming convention for all its class files.  This means models (and all classes) should be placed based on their **full class name**.

When you say

```
php artisan make:model SomeModel
```

You're actually creating a model with the full name of `App\SomeModel`, so `artisan` creates the following file.

```
app/SomeModel.php
```

If you said

```
php artisan make:model 'Test\SomeModel'
```

you'd be creating a model with the full name `App\Test\SomeModel`, and Laravel would create the following file

```
app/Test/SomeModel.php
```

So, its your model's full class name (namespace included) that determines where the class definition file is.

Comment: I tried this in Laravel 5 and when giving a path for Model file, I had to mention the path without the single quotes like you mentioned. This worked for me:  `php artisan make:model Test\SomeModel`

Comment: @Alan: Is there any specific reason for removing models directory from Laravel 5 ?

Comment: @Ashish Conforming to PHP standards for namespaces, and the consistency of having all application classes autoload the same way.

Answer (score 14):

I found it should be:

```
php artisan make:model ModelFolder\\SomeModel
```

Comment: actually it should have one backslash

Comment: That could very well depend on your terminal...?

Comment: Looking at Laravel source code, if you give the path as `app/myspace/etc`
Laravel internally changes all `/`  to `\\` using `str_replace()`, so using either single forward slash 'OR' double backslash (i.e. escaped) should work, it's your choice!

Comment: I tried with one slash but it created the file with folder name. While its working fine with double slashes in laravel 6.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create Models manually on specific folder. Example if you want to create model `info`into folder `Models`. Create file named `info.php` inside folder Models that you created before. Here are you should write code like this in `info.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Info extends Model
{
    // your code
    protected $table = 'tb_users';
}
```

Of course you also can use Artisan command 
`php artisan make:model "Models\Info"`

If you want to call that model `Info` you create a view

```
<?php
$users = App\Models\Info::all();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->name;
}
```

It will display all name of users

Answer (score 0):

You could also look at www/yourfolder/database/php file created when the model was created.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! This seems to be more like a comment. Please do not write comments as answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you too lazy and don't want to type the word `Models` every time, you can try this my https://github.com/bangnokia/laravel-models-folder

Answer (score 0):

Look into this using this tutorial on medium https://medium.com/@codingcave/organizing-your-laravel-models-6b327db182f9. 
Its a better solution to extend the `ModelMakeCommand` so that instead of `php artisan make:model 'Test\SomeModel'` you will run `php artisan make:model SomeModel` and you'll still get `'Test\SomeModel'` namespace with `SomeModel.php` in `'Test'` folder